# Reverse an expression in the output?

Tags: output, rotation

I have a recurrence relation in output and Mathematica give me in output the reverse order of what I want, for example

> {-5 (2 n - 7) (3 n - 10) (3 n - 7) , 0,0,(6 n - 19) (6 n - 13), (6 n -7),(462722852867 n^3 -962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 n - 627172524720)}

in the output I get

> -5 (2 n - 7) (3 n - 10) (3 n - 7)a[n-5]+(6 n - 19) (6 n - 13)a[n-2]+ (6 n -7)a[n-1]+( 462722852867 n^3 -962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 n - 627172524720)a[n]

but I want

> ( 462722852867 n^3 -962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 n - 627172524720)a[n]+ (6 n -7)a[n-1]+(6 n - 19) (6 n - 13)a[n-2]-5 (2 n - 7) (3 n - 10) (3 n - 7)a[n-5]+

I tried these commands

```
Reverse[]
RotateLeft[]
RotateRight[]
```

but the output still the same

Thank you.

---

A larger example, not in the desired order:

```
-576 (-9 + n) (-8 + n) (-7 + n) (-35 + 3 n) (-31 + 3 n) (-28 + 
    3 n) (-23 + 3 n) (-20 + 3 n) (-19 + 3 n) (-17 + 3 n) (-16 + 
    3 n) (-14 + 3 n) (-13 + 3 n) (-10 + 3 n) (-7 + 3 n) a[-14 + n] + 
 5 (-8 + n) (-7 + n) (-5 + n) (-28 + 3 n) (-20 + 3 n) (-17 + 
    3 n) (-16 + 3 n) (-14 + 3 n) (-13 + 3 n) (-10 + 3 n) (-7 + 
    3 n) (-57 + 5 n) (-49 + 5 n) (-41 + 5 n) (-33 + 5 n) a[-6 + n] - 
 5 (-7 + n) (-17 + 3 n) (-14 + 3 n) (-13 + 3 n) (-10 + 3 n) (-7 + 
    3 n) (-7132966283520 + 9021347689536 n - 5006624101088 n^2 + 
    1601473586668 n^3 - 325587246373 n^4 + 43652805122 n^5 - 
    3861437250 n^6 + 217395000 n^7 - 7070625 n^8 + 101250 n^9) a[-5 + 
    n] + 5 (-14 + 3 n) (-10 + 3 n) (-7 + 3 n) (23357124762753600 - 
    43564137549957360 n + 36775008279260204 n^2 - 
    18593224893612441 n^3 + 6274748858601497 n^4 - 
    1489842040904040 n^5 + 255310266461696 n^6 - 31828995825234 n^7 + 
    2865910980978 n^8 - 181809090000 n^9 + 7715209500 n^10 - 
    196678125 n^11 + 2278125 n^12) a[-4 + n] - 
 10 (-19 + 3 n) (-7 + 3 n) (-91605709055952000 + 
    211605862175890560 n - 221164472227884248 n^2 + 
    138679631057141024 n^3 - 58274719204472912 n^4 + 
    17346580037124671 n^5 - 3766312275861722 n^6 + 
    604367447829986 n^7 - 71720894959443 n^8 + 6220126970109 n^9 - 
    383392845000 n^10 + 15911397000 n^11 - 398671875 n^12 + 
    4556250 n^13) a[-3 + n] +  5 (-23 + 3 n) (-19 + 3 n) (-16 + 3 n) (1868204798460000 - 
    4872003910332720 n + 5568683824220146 n^2 - 
    3705906207430371 n^3 + 1605611503276213 n^4 - 
    478711029627885 n^5 + 100995656823529 n^6 - 15227970369864 n^7 + 
    1631911034772 n^8 - 121434130125 n^9 + 5964951375 n^10 - 
    173896875 n^11 + 2278125 n^12) a[-2 + n] - 
 5 (-9 + n) (-23 + 3 n) (-20 + 3 n) (-19 + 3 n) (-16 + 3 n) (-13 + 
    3 n) (-172642368360 + 467904529078 n - 471632902377 n^2 + 
    247446259858 n^3 - 76729280622 n^4 + 14835851470 n^5 - 
    1808908500 n^6 + 135189000 n^7 - 5653125 n^8 + 101250 n^9) a[-1 + 
    n] - 5 (-9 + n) (-8 + n) n (-31 + 3 n) (-23 + 3 n) (-20 + 
    3 n) (-19 + 3 n) (-17 + 3 n) (-16 + 3 n) (-13 + 3 n) (-10 + 
    3 n) (-56 + 5 n) (-42 + 5 n) (-28 + 5 n) (-14 + 5 n) a[n]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want the output to be in a given order?

Comment: @kiro because I have many recurrences relations and to find the general recurrence I need to write all these recurrences in  specific order to understand the general case. ^_^

Comment: actually  it's ( 462722852867 n^3 -962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 n- 627172524720), sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```
in = -5 (2 n - 7) (3 n - 10) (3 n - 7) a[n - 5] + (6 n - 19) (6 n - 13) a[
     n - 2] + (6 n - 7) a[
     n - 1] + (462722852867 n^3 - 962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 n - 
      627172524720) a[n];

in /. Plus -> (Defer[+##] ~Reverse~ {2} &)
```

> ```
> a[n] (462722852867 n^3 - 962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 n - 627172524720) + 
>  a[n - 1] (6 n - 7) + a[n - 2] (6 n - 19) (6 n - 13) - 
>  5 a[n - 5] (3 n - 10) (2 n - 7) (3 n - 7)
> ```

With [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html)

```
TraditionalForm[in] /. Plus -> (Defer[+##]~Reverse~{2} &)
```

[image]

---

For your larger example using [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) in place of [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) seems to get the main order right, but the suborder is not as desired.

```
in = (* big input *)

TraditionalForm[in] /. Plus -> (HoldForm[+##] ~Reverse~ {2} &)
```

[image]

I am still seeking a *simple* way to get this all correct.

---

This is pretty ugly but after half an hour I haven't come up with anything better.

```
in /. Plus -> (HoldForm[+##] ~Reverse~ {2} &)
First[List @@@ Map[ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &, %, {2}]];
HoldForm[+##] & @@ % // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when I convert it to `TraditionalForm`   I lost the order again???

Comment: @OAMAZF Please see update.

Comment: It works for small recurrence but if the number of terms became big then I lost the order for example:
[Example](http://wikisend.com/download/500378/Example).

Comment: @OAMAZF I added that larger example to your Question for others to reference.  Please describe the ordering that you desire.

Comment: I want to write my recurrence relation as we write it in math, for example the Fibonacci recurrence $F_n-F_{n-1}-F_{n-2}$ we remark that the order is from $n$ to $n-2$. for the output of Mathematica, I get $F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}-F{n}$ the order from $n-2$ to $n$
for a generale case
I want $Coeff_1\; a[n]+Coeff_2\; a[n-1]+\cdots+Coeff_p\; a[n-p]$ instead of $Coeff_p\;a[n-p]+\cdots+Coeff_2\;a[n-1]+Coeff_1\;a[n]$

Comment: @OAMAZF Thank you for clarifying; I shall see if I can make my code work more reliably.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mr.Wuzard, that is satisfactory for me.

Answer (score 0):

Defining your polynomial as q, you can get the coefficients of the a[n] using CoefficientList.

```
q = -5 (2 n - 7) (3 n - 10) (3 n - 7) a[n - 5] + 
    (6 n - 19) (6 n - 13) a[n - 2] + (6 n - 7) a[n - 1] + 
    (462722852867 n^3 - 962875190792 n^2 + 1166698625652 - 627172524720) a[n]

CoefficientList[q, {a[n-5], a[n - 4], a[n - 3], a[n - 2], a[n - 1], a[n]}]
```

Comment: I want to modify the order of the output as the example in the question, the output give me this order (a[n-5],a[n-4],a[n-3,a[n-2],a[n-1],a[n]) and I want to display it like this (a[n],a[n-1],a[n-2],a[n-3],a[n-4],a[n-5])

Comment: The order of the coefficients is pretty easy to rearrange. See edit..